# CakePHP how to use the PaginatorHelper output follows the effect?

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I hope the output effect:

```
<li class="prev"><a href="xxx"><i class="icon-previous"></i></a></li>
```

The Official Handbook:

```
You can change the wrapping tag using the tag option:

    echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('previous'), array('tag' => 'li'));

Output:

    <li class="prev">
      <a rel="prev" href="/posts/index/page:1/sort:title/order:desc">
        previous
      </a>
    </li>
```

I imitate the way it:

```
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('<i class="icon-previous"></i>'), array('tag' => 'li'));
?>
```

But the output is:

```
<li class="prev">&lt;i class="icon-previous"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</li>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev(
    __('previous'), 
    array('tag' => 'li', 'class' => 'icon-previous')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('<i class="icon-previous"></i>'), 
    array(
        'tag' => 'li', 
        'escape'=>false
));
```

Also make sure there IS a previous record otherwise the  tag is omitted anyway